# Porque no funciona este filtrado con react?

Tags: reactjs, filtro, usestate, next

Qué está mal para que no funcione esto?

Tengo este array de objetos

```
const videos = [
        { created: "", duration: 0 },
        { created: "", duration: 2 },
        { created: "", duration: 1 },
        { created: "", duration: 4 },
        { created: "", duration: 6 },
        { created: "", duration: -2 }
]
```

Quiero ordenarlos por filtros, ahora mismo solo por duracion, ascendente o descendente.

Este es el código que tengo con typescript:

Componente VideoList

```
/* COMPONENTS */
import InputSelect from "../Input/InputSelect";
import styles from "./VideoList.module.scss";

/* UTILS & HOOKS */
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

/* INTERFACES */
// Formato de fecha temporal: 'dd-MM-YYTHH:mm'
interface IVideo {
  created: string;
  duration: number;
}

interface VideoListProps {
  title: string;
  videos: IVideo[];
}

const VideoList = ({ title, videos }: VideoListProps) => {
  const [filterSelected, setFilterSelected] = useState<string>("");
  const [sortedVideos, setSortedVideos] = useState<IVideo[]>([]);

  const options = [
    "Por fecha - creciente",
    "Por fecha - decreciente",
    "Por duración - creciente",
    "Por duración - decreciente",
  ];

  const sortByFilter = (filter: string, videos: IVideo[]): IVideo[] => {
    switch (filter) {
      case options[2]:
        return [...videos.sort((a, b) => a.duration + b.duration)];
      case options[3]:
        return [...videos.sort((a, b) => a.duration - b.duration)];
      default:
        return [{ created: "", duration: 10000 }];
    }
  };

  console.log('er')

  const handleFilterChange = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFilterSelected(e.target.value);
    setSortedVideos(sortByFilter(filterSelected, videos));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h4>{title}</h4>
      <section className={styles.videolist_section}>
        <InputSelect
          name={"filter"}
          title={"Ordenar por"}
          label={*El nombre de la opción*}
          options={options}
          onChange={handleFilterChange}
          optional={true}
        />
        <h3>{filterSelected}</h3>
        {sortedVideos.length > 0
          ? sortedVideos.map((video) => {
              return <h1 key={video.duration}>{video.duration}</h1>;
            })
          : videos.map((video) => {
              <h3>{video.duration}</h3>;
            })}
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default VideoList;
```

Sin más, lo que hace es que cada vez que cambia la selección del input, actualiza el estado de filterSelected y en base a este reordena el array videosSorted. Bien pues no funciona correctamente, primero que el algoritmo de ordenación no da lo que debe dar, no entiendo por qué, y luego la renderización no se hace correctamente, y creo que la actualización de los estados tampoco.

¿Alguna idea de qué le puede pasar o cómo arreglarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto al algoritmo de ordenación, debería ser:

```js
[...videos.sort((a, b) => a.duration - b.duration)]
//...Para ordenar de forma ascendente
```

Y

```js
[...videos.sort((a, b) => b.duration - a.duration)]
//...Para ordenar de forma descendente
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, el problema no es el algoritmo de ordenación, si no que no se renderiza el array bien, y pienso que es porque no se actualizan los estados o se hacen de forma asíncrona, y no sé cómo ponerle solución

Comment: @lRetro Tu pregunta dice "primero que el algoritmo de ordenación no da lo que debe dar". Y te garantizo que así como está en tu pregunta no funciona. Lo que tienes en el case para la opción "Por duración - decreciente" de hecho ordena de forma creciente. Y lo que tienes en el case de "Por duración - creciente" es simplemente incorrecto.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en en el spread operator, estas sin querer, mutando el estado original y en react eso no está permitido. Solo se permite a través del los set de los useState o con un setState en su defecto.
Podrías realizar lo siguiente y avisarnos como te va:

```
const [sortedVideos, setSortedVideos] = useState<IVideo[]>(videos);

 const sortByFilter = (filter: string): IVideo[] => {
    switch (filter) {
      case options[2]:
        return [...sortedVideos.sort((a, b) => a.duration + b.duration)];
      case options[3]:
        return [...sortedVideos.sort((a, b) => a.duration - b.duration)];
      default:
        return [{ created: "", duration: 10000 }];
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu aporte, con este cambio directamente no produce ninguna ordenación, en todos los casos entra por el caso default

Comment: Bien, vamos a ir paso por paso entonces antes. que pasa si antes del switch haces un console.log(filter, filter === options[2], filter === [options3]), por que me suene que si siempre entra al default no está acertando dentro del switch